# Install dependencies from setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, install-requires

I wonder if as well as .deb packages for example, it is possible in my setup.py I configure the dependencies for my package, and run:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

They are installed automatically. Already researched the internet but all I found out just leaving me confused, things like "requires", "install_requires" and "requirements.txt"

Comment: One good answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743115/2514803

Answer (score 41):

Just create `requirements.txt` in your lib folder and add all dependencies like this:

```
gunicorn
docutils>=0.3
lxml==0.5a7
```

Then create a `setup.py` script and read `requirements.txt`:

```
import os
lib_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
requirement_path = f"{lib_folder}/requirements.txt"
install_requires = [] # Here we'll add: ["gunicorn", "docutils>=0.3", "lxml==0.5a7"]
if os.path.isfile(requirement_path):
    with open(requirement_path) as f:
        install_requires = f.read().splitlines()
setup(name="mypackage", install_requires=install_requires, [...])
```

The execution of `python setup.py install` will install your package and all dependencies. Like @jwodder said it is not mandatory to create a `requirements.txt` file, you can just set `install_requires` directly in the `setup.py` script. But writing a `requirements.txt` file is a best practice.

In the `setup` function call, you also have to set `version`, `packages`, `author`, etc, read the doc for a complete example: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html

Your package directory should look like this:

```
├── mypackage
│   ├── mypackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mymodule.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
```

Comment: `install_requires = list(f.read().splitlines())` is much more straightforward than appending one line at a time in a loop. (The `list` call may or may not be necessary; test and see.)

Comment: Or maybe something like `[line for line in f.read().splitlines() if len(line) > 0]` to prevent blank lines

Comment: Or you could just forego the `requirements.txt` file entirely and write `setup(install_requires=['gunicorn', 'docutils>=0.3', 'lxml==0.5a7'], ...)` directly in your `setup.py`.

Comment: I'd add, one should ignore comments and whitespaces prefix 
`install_requires = [line for line in map(str.lstrip, f.read().splitlines())
                        if len(line) > 0 and
                        not line.startswith('#')]`

Comment: This will connect to the internet and install all the dependencies right? how can I instruct it to install from a local repo? will simply doing ```pip install mypacke.whl --no-index --find-links deps_folder``` do the trick?

Comment: While all proposed solutions so far somehow parse the `requirements.txt` file and use these dependencies as `install_requires` in the `setup.py`, there is an argument whether this is a good practice or not: https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Answer (score 10):

Another possible solution

```py
try:
    # for pip >= 10
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError:
    # for pip <= 9.0.3
    from pip.req import parse_requirements

def load_requirements(fname):
    reqs = parse_requirements(fname, session="test")
    return [str(ir.req) for ir in reqs]

setup(name="yourpackage", install_requires=load_requirements("requirements.txt"))
```

Comment: This worked for me. No idea how this would fail in the future though (if it ever fails).

Comment: @muammar it could fail because pip is explicitly not supposed to be used programmatically. See that `_` in `pip._internal.req`? That means it's part of a package's internals, which shouldn't be used externally and may change without warning. There is absolutely no guarantee that it won't suddenly change, and in fact it has.

Answer (score 7):

You generate egg information from your `setup.py`, then you use the `requirements.txt` from these egg information:

```bash
$ python setup.py egg_info
$ pip install -r <your_package_name>.egg-info/requires.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.4+, it is possible to use the `Path` class from `pathlib`, to do effectively the same thing as @hayj answer.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import setuptools

...

def get_install_requires() -> List[str]:
    """Returns requirements.txt parsed to a list"""
    fname = Path(__file__).parent / 'requirements.txt'
    targets = []
    if fname.exists():
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            targets = f.read().splitlines()
    return targets

...

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    install_requires=get_install_requires(),
    ...
)
```