# How to use setup.py to install dependencies only?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am not interested in installing  my package itself but I am interested installing all the dependencies used by my package. Is there a way to do this using `setup.py`? It seems `setup.py` installs my package and all dependencies.

Comment: So, you have package `abc` which is dependent on `xyz`, you want to install `xyz` but not `abc` am i right ?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#easy-install-find-and-install-packages

Comment: If the package you downloaded has a requirements file, it's as easy as `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Please vote for this request to get a better solution: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the -e flag on pip install

```
pip install -e .
```

Comment: I'm confused by this - `-e` is for "editable mode", which will do things like symlink the working directories of dependencies.  In this case OP wants to install everything "for real", just not the one package under development.  Does this handle the use case well?

Comment: @KenWilliams editable mode will install everything "for real", *except* for the very package you're working on (this will be "symlinked", as you mentioned). You might not want this link to remain though -- which is what your trick with as subsequent `pip uninstall` handles.

Comment: this is obviously not the right answer! Why is this accepted? This will do much more than "only install dependencies".

Comment: Please vote for this request to get a better solution: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440

Answer (score 14):

The only way I've found to reliably do this in a straightforward manner is this:

```
pip install . && pip uninstall `python setup.py --name`
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. One minor suggestion: `pip uninstall --yes`, so it doesn't prompt you (e.g. in a Dockerfile)

Comment: This is great answer! One minor comment is that it does not work for python3, however it is easy to adapt.

Comment: @QiLuo I use this with python 3, what problem did you encounter?

Comment: In an environment with both python2 and python3, I could use ``pip3 install . && pip3 uninstall `python3 setup.py --name` ``

Comment: @QiLuo Yeah, that's just because pip and python are apparently called `pip3` and `python3` in your environment.  In mine, they're simply called `pip` and `python`.

Comment: Please vote for this request to get a better solution: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440

Answer (score 1):

if you wan to do it from setup.py do:

```
python setup.py egg_info
pip install -r *.egg-info/requires.txt
rm -rf *.egg-info/
```

all of this ran from the project folder usually for me it's the root of my github where setup.py is.

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53251585/1601580

Comment: Exactly what I wanted for my docker container!